# Проблемы с обработкой массива

Tags: java

*K* раз подаются пары значений a и b, в массиве [1-10] нужно заменить все значения на 0, которые попадают в диапазон a и b включительно. Никак не могу понять, почему при обработке последней пары чисел, цикл останавливается не заменив на 0 значение b.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length ; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == a) {
                while (a<=b) {
                    arr[j] = 0;
                    ++a;
                    ++j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ввод: 8 10; 2 5; 3 6;
выводит: 1000067000

Comment: у тебя нет условия выхода.... получается безконечный цикл....
читай - for - j=0, пока j меньше длины массива (какого массива??)
если `j`-тый элемент массива равен значению `а`, то - 
пока `a` меньше либо равно `б`  `j`-тый элемент массива - присвоить 0
`а++`
`J++`
чувчтвуешь отсувствие логики?

Comment: нет, все ровно не особо понимаю, к сожалению, Смотри, я через скан получаю  K раз пару значений a и b, потом потом через for прохожу по всему массиву [1-10] и нахожу элемент а, после этого меняю его на 0 и последующие до б, через while (a== b) все, выхожу и пробегаюсь дальше по циклу в поисках совпадений. Потом беру следующую пару и проверяю все заново.

Comment: ну что, получилось?

Answer (score 0):

пробуй....

```
public class TestTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1; //замени на скан
        int b = 8; // замени на скан
        int[] arr = {1, 2,12,15, 3, 4, 5, 11};
//проходим по всему массиву
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            //если i-тый элемент меньше либо b,
//            если i-тый элемент ,больше либо a
            // то заменяем его на 0
            if (arr[i] <= b && arr[i] >= a) {
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); //[0, 0, 12, 15, 0, 0, 0, 11]
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. На входе пары значений, а массив 1..10. У вас же массив захардкожен а пары .. всего одна и тоже хардкод 1 и 8. А на выходе вообще какая-то мешанина )

Comment: то, что написано у меня, так же работает, если пара сканируется 1 раз, и 2 раза тоже работает, а вот 3 пара не отрабатывает, даже при увеличении массива до 20, именно последнее значение не отрабатывает до конца

Answer (score 0):

вот рабочий вариант

```
for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if ( j == a - 1){
            while (a <= b){
                arr[j] = 0;
                j++;
                a++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```